# How to connect mongoDB into React webpack

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, express, webpack

I Have a web app I created using React with Webpack to handle babel and SASS.  I have react router setup on my nav bar and can navigate nicely.  I just added a contact form page where I handle the data with a React component, I now want to send this data to mongoDB.  In the past I have made an express w/handlebars / mongoose app in order to grab and hold data on mongoDB.  My question is...

How can I connect express to my React app without messing up Webpack dev server configs and my react routing?  Do I need express to connect into mongoDB?  I am just trying to send my contact form data to mongoDB and retrieve later.

my package.json and webpack.config.js files are listed below for my project.

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');


var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './app/App.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public',
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig],
  devServer: {
       inline:true,
       contentBase: './public',
       port: 3333
     },
  module: {
    loaders: [{ 
         test: /\.js$/, 
         exclude: /node_modules/, 
         loader: "babel-loader"
      },
        {
              test: /\.scss$/,
              loader: 'style!css!sass'
            }]
  }
};
```

package.json ....

```
{
  "name": "newaccount",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "a form submission for new accounts",
  "main": "App.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "---",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "moongoose": "0.0.5",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.13.0",
    "sass": "^0.5.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way you could send data from your web application to your web server (which I'm assuming communicates with your mongoDB) is via a web API call. Going forward I'm going to  use the assumption that you've used `express` to setup a simple POST request on your web server under the route `/api/data`.

Assuming you're not using something like Flux or Redux in your implementation, you could invoke a POST request to your web API like so:

```
var React = require('react');
var fetch = require('whatwg-fetch');

var MyComp = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            dataToSend: { id: 0, data: ["foo", "bar"] },
            status: null,
            response: null
        };
    },

    handleSendData: function (e) {
        // Set status to 'posting...' and kick off the post
        this.setState({ status: 'Posting...' }, this.postData);
    },

    postData: function() {
        fetch('/api/data', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state.dataToSend)
        }).then(function(response) {
            return response.json()
        }).then(function(json) {
            this.setState({ response: json, status: 'Done.' });
        }).catch(function(ex) {
            this.setState({ status: 'error!' });
            console.log('parsing failed', ex)
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleSendData}>Send Data</button>
                <div>{this.state.status}</div>
                <div>{this.state.response}</div>
            </div>
    }
});

module.exports = MyComp;
```

In the code above I invoke the request from a button click and then handle any response from the server to update my component's state. The example uses the `fetch` functionality provided by the `whatwg-fetch` module but you can use something else if you want such as an `AJAX` call via `jQuery`.

Comment: That looks good.  I haven't yet setup express and I'm currently using hardcoded dummy data because I am not certain how express will conflict with React Router & Webpack

Comment: I usually have my server running with express separately from my React project. I then use webpack to bundle my JavaScript and just reference in the tiny HTML file my express server sends back (to host my React project).

Comment: So you setup an express server then reference the bundle.js that webpack makes and don't use webpack-dev-server?

Comment: For development, sure I use the webpack-dev-server to host my React project to make easy use of the hot loader but I still run my Node server separately so I can access my web API (or I mock out the function that would do the `fetch` call to simply return static data). I don't know if that's the best setup but it's how I've done it and it works for me.